# Isomorphic or equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, terminology, equivalence-relations

Let $\sim_n$ be the usual equivalence relation of congruence modulo $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\sim_nb\Leftrightarrow a-b=k\cdot n$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

For $n=0$ **the element** in the equivalence class of, say, $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ **is just $a$ itself**. So to every element of $\mathbb{Z}/\sim_0$ corresponds one, and only one, element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is:

> What is mathematically more correct, to say that the two sets $\mathbb{Z}/\sim_0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are **equal** or to say that those rings are **isomorphic**?

Comment: Well, the two sets are definitely not equal, as one is $\{0,1,-1,...\}$ and the other is $\{\{0\},\{1\},...\}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so what is correct is $\mathbb{Z}/\sim_0\simeq\mathbb{Z}$? The equality is, therefore, just a language abuse.

Comment: Right, they are isomorphic (both as sets and as rings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should state the question more general:

Given a commutative ring $R$ with identity and an ideal $I \subseteq R$, we can always build the quotient $R/I$. Now we can ask: Is $R/\{0\}$ equal to $R$ or are they just isomorphic?

**Point of view 1**: Let us define $R/I = \{a + I \mid a \in R\}$ together with the usual addition and multiplication of cosets. Then we have $R/\{0\} = \{a + \{0\} \mid a \in R\} = \{\{a\} \mid a \in R\}$. This is not equal to $R$ as $\{a\} \neq a$, but the ring homomorphism $R \to R/\{0\}, a \mapsto \{a\}$ is always an isomorphism.

**Point of view 2**: We define $R/I$ a bit more categorical as follows: For $R/I$ we choose some ring together with a surjective ring homomorphism $\pi: R \to R/I$ such that $\text{ker}(\pi) = I$.
The process of choosing could go like that: If $I \neq \{0\}$ we let $R/I = \{a + I \mid a \in R\}$ and $\pi: R \to R/I$ be the natural projection. If $I = \{0\}$ we let $R/I = R$ and $\pi: R \to R/I$ the identity.
Now the identity $\text{id}: R \to R$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel $\{0\}$, so this is indeed well defined.

I prefer point of view $2$: In fact, just using this definition (and not the construction!) allows us to prove every statements about quotient rings we want to have. Also it's easier to use, as we don't get confused by cosets, if we don't want to. The first definition just exists to prove that a ring with the properties of the second definition does always exist.

Comment: The second one does not allow you to conclude that they are equal unless you work in a skeleton of the category of rings.

Comment: Depends on when we choose the specific representative of all rings satisfying the second definition. Most of the time it's okay to choose it in the given situation.

Comment: But that is not how you defined it. You said it was "some ring" with the given property, which only defines it up to isomorphism.

Comment: Hhm, yes, that's true. I don't know how to change it correctly, but what I wanted to say is: There is no problem with choosing $R/\{0\}$ to be $R$ itself. But yes, to be precise we have to choose.

Comment: So @LeonLang , it all leads, ultimately, to isomorphisms?

Comment: I changed the answer so we really have equality. It's important for me to point out that choosing like that doesn't make problems. As I said, the construction is not important and we can prove everything we wish just with the given property. So, if you decide to see $R/\{0\}$ to be $R$ itself, then you can really do it.